# Проблемы с регулярным выражением

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

По регулярному выражению находится не то, что нужно. Вот код:

```
reg_exp = re.compile(r"(A+)|(B+)")
print(reg_exp.findall("AAABBAA"))
```

Должно быть выведено: `['AAA', 'BB', 'AA']`
Выводится: `[('AAA', ''), ('', 'BB'), ('AA', '')]`
Откуда появились эти кортежи с пустыми строками? Как переписать регулярное выражение так, чтобы возвращалось то, что нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Скобок то у Вас сколько? Две пары? Вот питон и выводит. Ответ абсолютно логичный и правильный. Но если хочется по другому, то тогда и выражение напишите по другому

```
reg_exp = re.compile(r"(A+|B+)")
print(reg_exp.findall("AAABBAA"))
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас появляются кортежи из двух элементов, потому что у вас две захватывающие скобки. Один элемент кортежа соответствует удовлетворенному условию ИЛИ из регулярного выражения, а другой - неудовлетворенному. Вы можете сделать их незахватывающими:

```
import re

reg_exp = re.compile(r"(?:A+)|(?:B+)")
print(reg_exp.findall("AAABBAA"))
```

Тогда результат будет

```
['AAA', 'BB', 'AA']
```

Вариант без скобок тоже работает

```
import re

reg_exp = re.compile(r"A+|B+")
print(reg_exp.findall("AAABBAA"))
```